# How to write multiple "JOIN"'s and "ON"'s in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT name FROM people AS p
JOIN directors AS d ON d.person_id = p.id
JOIN stars AS s ON s.person_id = p.id
JOIN movies AS m ON m.id = d.movie_id
AND m.id = s.movie_id
WHERE m.title LIKE 'Toy Story%'
```

I want to write a SQL query to list the names of all people who starred in Toy Story. And I get this error.

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: interrupted
```

Tables:

```
movies (id INTEGER, title TEXT NOT NULL, year NUMERIC, PRIMARY KEY(id));

stars (movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL, person_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id), FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id));

directors (movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL, person_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id), FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id));

ratings (movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL, rating REAL NOT NULL, votes INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id));

people (id INTEGER, name TEXT NOT NULL, birth NUMERIC, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Are there really no other more detailed error messages?

Comment: @ADyson I'm using DB browser

Comment: That sounds like some sort of front-end client tool. It's unlikely to be relevant. I asked which DBMS (i.e. database engine) you are using? e.g. MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, SQLite, MariaDB...etc. (You should always tag your question with that as well as the "sql" tag in StackOverflow - the guidance for the SQL tag even instructs you to do that - did you read it when you were selecting that tag?)

Comment: you are getting error probably here "AND m.id = s.movie_id" , with 1 join you can join 2 tables not 3, you have to join again with stars

Comment: @ADyson I don't know. But I used "sqlite3" command. Maybe its somehow connected

Comment: I find it a bit baffling that someone can set up a database without knowing what kind of database it is. Aren't you interested in what tools you are using? But `sqlite3` is the clue ...it's SQLite (which was in my list of likely possibilities).

Comment: Anyway it's hard to test without having any sample data provided or a more precise error message, but, speculatively, I'd try moving `AND m.id = s.movie_id` into your WHERE clause instead of in the join

Comment: It's the assignment and everything already set up for me, all I should do is write queries. Btw I only started learning SQL,  could you recommend some material for beginners? @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson Like this?  "WHERE m.title LIKE 'Toy Story%' AND m.id = s.movie_id"

Comment: yes. Just try it please.

Comment: @ADyson same error

Comment: Ok. well the error message is pretty much useless unfortunately, it says nothing about the underlying problem. Please provide sample data from your database, and indicate the results you expect from such data with your query, so we can see if we get the same error when trying to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to list both directors and stars (both belonging to persons) you have to get the names of directors and stars separately and union them.
Note: Use UNION if you want to merge duplicate records

```
SELECT name FROM people AS p
JOIN directors AS d ON d.person_id = p.id
JOIN movies AS m ON m.id = d.movie_id
WHERE m.title LIKE 'Toy Story%'
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM people AS p
JOIN starts AS s ON s.person_id = p.id
JOIN movies AS m ON m.id = d.movie_id
WHERE m.title LIKE 'Toy Story%'
```